# Error while initializing Firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, dart, web, mobile, flutter-web

My `main.dart`:

```
void main() async {
  await preinit();

  await di<FirebaseAuthService>().useEmulator();
  await di<FirebaseFunctionsService>().useEmulator();

  await initApp();
}
```

Part of my `FirebaseAuthService`:

```
@singleton
class FirebaseAuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _service;

  FirebaseAuthService(FirebaseCoreService firebaseCoreService)
      : _service = FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: firebaseCoreService.app);
}
```

Part of my `FirebaseFunctionsService`:

```
@injectable
class FirebaseFunctionsService {
  final FirebaseFunctions _service;

  FirebaseFunctionsService(FirebaseCoreService firebaseCoreService)
      : _service = FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(app: firebaseCoreService.app);
}
```

My `FirebaseCoreService`:

```
@singleton
class FirebaseCoreService {
  final FirebaseApp _app;

  FirebaseApp get app => _app;

  FirebaseCoreService._(this._app);

  @factoryMethod
  static Future<FirebaseCoreService> create() async {
    final app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance
          .setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(!kDebugMode);
    }
    return FirebaseCoreService._(app);
  }
}
```

At `Firebase.initializeApp` that is called right after `preinit()` in `main.dart`, I get the following error:

```
"Error: Invalid argument(s): object cannot be a num, string, bool, or null
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:5080:11)
    at JsObject.fromBrowserObject (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:61852:19)
    at get [_ignoredServiceScripts] (http://localhost:50958/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:147:35)
    at firebase_core_web.FirebaseCoreWeb.new._initializeCore (http://localhost:50958/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:182:27)
    at _initializeCore.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at [_initializeCore] (http://localhost:50958/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:177:20)
    at firebase_core_web.FirebaseCoreWeb.new.initializeApp (http://localhost:50958/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:199:36)
    at initializeApp.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at firebase_core_web.FirebaseCoreWeb.new.initializeApp (http://localhost:50958/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:198:20)
    at initializeApp (http://localhost:50958/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core.dart.lib.js:105:59)
    at initializeApp.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at Firebase.initializeApp (http://localhost:50958/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core.dart.lib.js:104:20)
    at create (http://localhost:50958/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/data/firebase/firebase_core_service.dart.lib.js:26:49)
    at create.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at FirebaseCoreService.create (http://localhost:50958/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/data/firebase/firebase_core_service.dart.lib.js:25:20)
    at http://localhost:50958/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/domain/theme_manager.dart.lib.js:1903:130
    at get_it_helper.GetItHelper.new.singletonAsync (http://localhost:50958/packages/injectable/src/get_it_helper.dart.lib.js:117:18)
    at $36initGetIt (http://localhost:50958/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/domain/theme_manager.dart.lib.js:1903:16)
    at $36initGetIt.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at Object.$36initGetIt [as $initGetIt] (http://localhost:50958/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/domain/theme_manager.dart.lib.js:1900:18)
    at configureDependencies (http://localhost:50958/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/domain/theme_manager.dart.lib.js:1918:32)
    at configureDependencies.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at Object.configureDependencies (http://localhost:50958/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/domain/theme_manager.dart.lib.js:1917:18)
    at preinit (http://localhost:50958/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/main.dart.lib.js:55:16)
    at preinit.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at Object.preinit (http://localhost:50958/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/main.dart.lib.js:52:18)
    at main$ (http://localhost:50958/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/main_local.dart.lib.js:18:18)
    at main$.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at main$ (http://localhost:50958/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/main_local.dart.lib.js:17:18)
    at http://localhost:50958/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:37:33
    at Object._checkAndCall (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:5279:16)
    at Object.dcall (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:5284:17)
    at http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:140291:18
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40641:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40511:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:35438:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:35999:49)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:36037:17)
    at [_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:35872:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:35906:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:40784:13)
    at http://localhost:50958/dart_sdk.js:36261:9"
```

My `ignoredServiceScripts` in `part of firebase_core_web`:

```
List<String> get _ignoredServiceScripts {
    try {
      JsObject ignored =
          JsObject.fromBrowserObject('flutterfire_ignore_scripts');

      if (ignored is Iterable) {
        return (ignored as Iterable)
            .map((e) => e.toString())
            .toList(growable: false);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Noop
    }

    return [];
  }
```

I don't get this error while running my app on iOS, for example. Can you please help?

**Update:**

I changed `JsObject.fromBrowserObject('flutterfire_ignore_scripts')` to `JsObject.fromBrowserObject(context['flutterfire_ignore_scripts'])`, so it doesn't fail with this error anymore, it does fail with another one (both on web, iOS, Android):

```
"Error: Expected a value of type 'Object', but got one of type 'Null'
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:5080:11)
    at Object.castError (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:5039:15)
    at Object.cast [as as] (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:5356:17)
    at Object.as (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:6603:31)
    at get [_ignoredServiceScripts] (http://localhost:59214/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:147:65)
    at firebase_core_web.FirebaseCoreWeb.new._initializeCore (http://localhost:59214/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:182:27)
    at _initializeCore.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at [_initializeCore] (http://localhost:59214/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:177:20)
    at firebase_core_web.FirebaseCoreWeb.new.initializeApp (http://localhost:59214/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:199:36)
    at initializeApp.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at firebase_core_web.FirebaseCoreWeb.new.initializeApp (http://localhost:59214/packages/firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart.lib.js:198:20)
    at initializeApp (http://localhost:59214/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core.dart.lib.js:105:59)
    at initializeApp.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at Firebase.initializeApp (http://localhost:59214/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core.dart.lib.js:104:20)
    at create (http://localhost:59214/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/data/firebase/firebase_core_service.dart.lib.js:26:49)
    at create.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at FirebaseCoreService.create (http://localhost:59214/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/data/firebase/firebase_core_service.dart.lib.js:25:20)
    at http://localhost:59214/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/domain/theme_manager.dart.lib.js:1903:130
    at get_it_helper.GetItHelper.new.singletonAsync (http://localhost:59214/packages/injectable/src/get_it_helper.dart.lib.js:117:18)
    at $36initGetIt (http://localhost:59214/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/domain/theme_manager.dart.lib.js:1903:16)
    at $36initGetIt.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at Object.$36initGetIt [as $initGetIt] (http://localhost:59214/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/domain/theme_manager.dart.lib.js:1900:18)
    at configureDependencies (http://localhost:59214/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/domain/theme_manager.dart.lib.js:1918:32)
    at configureDependencies.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at Object.configureDependencies (http://localhost:59214/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/domain/theme_manager.dart.lib.js:1917:18)
    at preinit (http://localhost:59214/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/main.dart.lib.js:55:16)
    at preinit.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at Object.preinit (http://localhost:59214/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/main.dart.lib.js:52:18)
    at main$ (http://localhost:59214/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/main_local.dart.lib.js:18:18)
    at main$.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40660:34)
    at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40691:7)
    at main$ (http://localhost:59214/packages/wa_flutter_questionnaire/main_local.dart.lib.js:17:18)
    at http://localhost:59214/web_entrypoint.dart.lib.js:37:33
    at Object._checkAndCall (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:5279:16)
    at Object.dcall (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:5284:17)
    at http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:140291:18
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40641:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40511:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:35438:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:35999:49)
    at _Future._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:36037:17)
    at [_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:35872:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:35906:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:40784:13)
    at http://localhost:59214/dart_sdk.js:36261:9"
```